# Add a column which is the divisible by 10 of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

A table called test has columns :

person_id (Unique) & special_num

Table:

[image: Table view]

Outcome :

[image: outcome]

Would like to create a new column called div to determine which person got the special_num that is divisible by 10 and which person did not instead of true or false would like to have a yes or no.

I am new to MySQL and have never tried it but gave it a shot please tell me how to get this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE special_num % 10 = 0 AS div from test;
```

I am unable to figure out how to input values and if it is the right way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [my SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e3f60/2) to mimic this problem.

First step is to create a new column by ALTERing the table.

```
ALTER TABLE PERSONS 
     ADD is_special VARCHAR(3);
```

Now run an UPDATE query that checks if the `special_num % 10` is zero or not, and if it is, then set `is_special` to `yes`.

```
UPDATE PERSONS SET is_special = CASE WHEN special_num % 10 = 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END;
```

Having said that, it is a bad idea to store values that are derived or calculated from other fields. You may want to use this in a view, but not in a table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *column*, then it goes in the `select`:

```
select t.*,
       ( (special_num % 10) = 0) as div
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN special_num % 10 = 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS `div`
FROM test
```